# Converting time_t to an int

Tags: c++, timestamp, unix-timestamp, static-cast

I want to convert the unix timestamp returned by time() as time_t to an integer. I've been searching for a solution for 20 minutes, and decided to ask here.

Every solution I have found has not worked. When trying to cast from time_t to int, I get errors:

```
long int t = static_cast<long int> time(NULL);
```

> error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'time'
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing '(' before identifier 'time'

I am very very new to C++. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `time_t` is a 64bit number on most modern platforms, casting to an `int` will lose data. Also the syntax is `static_cast<long int>(time(nullptr));`

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: FWIW, [Clang gives an even more readable error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c040377135ca49cd), and upon fixing that, [another simple error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cbfd604601847ba). There's absolutely no way to not figure it out with those.

Comment: ...and don't forget to `#include <time.h>` (or `#include <ctime>`, and use `std::time` instead).

Answer (score 3):

`time_t` is already an integer, though it's deliberately chosen to be one that stores the system's full range of UNIX time, so I would recommend *against* this cast.

However, if you insist, you're on the right lines but **just got the cast syntax wrong**.

In general, statically casting `e` to `T` looks like this:

```
static_cast<T>(e)  // <-- parentheses!
```

Just as the error message told you, you are "missing '(' before identifier 'time'".

So, your expression will be:

```
long int t = static_cast<long int>(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just read the errors and insert the *'missing ( before identifier time'*:

```
long int t = static_cast<long int>(time(NULL));
```

`static_cast` requires [the value to be encapsulated in parentheses](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/typecasting/staticcast.html).

Comment: Now I get this error:

`error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

Comment: @user3163947: Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. This is not a chatroom or discussion board. One question up there, one or more answers to _that_ question down here.

Answer (score 0):

simply add parenthesis around time(NULL):

```
long int t = static_cast<long int>(time(NULL));
```